# Error in haskell. Please guide me on how to fix this

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.List
step :: [Int] -> String -> [Int] 
step (x:y:ys) "*" = (x * y):ys
step (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys
step (x:y:ys) "-" = (y - x):ys
step xs numberString = read numberString:xs
```

This my code and error i keep getting is below, please any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
*Main> step [2+6]: this is what i put into my terminal

<interactive>:5:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (String -> [Int]))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
*Main>
```

Comment: You didn’t provide a value for `numberString`. `step [2, 6] "+"`?

Comment: Try using step [2+6] "" (notice a empty string as your accumulator).

Comment: As @Ry says, you need to apply `step` to 2 arguments if you want to actually see some output directly. The only reason I'm repeating that here is to point out that GHCi already pointed this out to you: `maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?`. Always read the whole of any error message, it's not infrequent that, as here, it will tell you exactly how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `step [2+6]` you are only partially applying your function, so the return value is not a list `[Int]`, but a function `String -> [Int]`. (Partially applying a function means to only provide some of the arguments it needs and getting a function back that takes the rest of the arguments. Yes, you can do this in Haskell!)

The error you see, will only arise in the terminal, because ghci tries to apply `show` to every statement, but functions are not showable.

So if you want to fully apply your function to see it in action, you need to provide all the arguments it needs, i.e.

```
step [1, 2, 3] "+"
```